# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'month'

Tags: python, django

I want to get the month of the next datetime date value, however I get the following error

```
i_real = (actividad.fecha_real_ini.month-1)
while i_real <=(actividad.fecha_real_fin.month-1):
      meses_real[i_real] = True
      i_real+=1
```

and I get the following error .

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Comment: Either `actividad.fecha_real_fin` or `actividad.fecha_real_ini` are null

Comment: in my model are declared  fecha_real_ini = models.DateTimeField()
    fecha_real_fin = models.DateTimeField()

Comment: So, one of them is null, ensure that they have value before trrying to access the month attribute

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention, either `actividad.fecha_real_ini` is None or `actividad.fecha_real_fin` is None. You need to ensure that the object is not None before accessing an attribute of the object.

You could also use the `getattr` python builtin for this; and supply a sensible default value in case of an `AttributeError`

The signature of `getattr` is: `getattr(object, attribute_name, default=None)`

For example, you could rewrite this as:

```
i_real = getattr(actividad.fecha_real_ini, 'month', 0)  # I am using 0 as my default; so i_real will be -1
while i_real <= (getattr(actividad.fecha_real_fin, 'month', 0)):
    meses_real[i_real-1] = True
    i_real += 1
```